# Qt Designer - Editor main window not the same height as resulting built main window

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

I'm very new to Qt and am having an issue regarding the window size after building the project. In the editor mode, I am placing a widget along with a pushbutton and textbox near the bottom. After I carefully align the pushbutton and textbox to be near the bottom of the window, I build the project. The resulting window shows a clear gap between the pushbutton/label and the bottom of the window:

[image: screenshot]

I feel like I'm in a position where I'm so new to Qt that I can't properly debug it. Would anyone here have any idea of what's causing this gap? Padding issue? OS specific issue?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't want to guess why window size is not the same, but you definitely should consider laying out your widgets with `QVBoxLayout`.

Comment: I can't see what exactly is causing the issue, but would like to share the observation that the header bar ("Type here") seems to be about the same height as the added space underneath. My guess is that that bar is hidden as it has no content and that's causing the whole remaining content to shift upwards. If you type something there it should fix this, but I would agree with @dvvrd that using a layout avoids these troubles.